# Добавление товаров в корзину PHP

Tags: php

Как реализовать функцию добавления товаров в корзину в куки на PHP?
Расскажите пожалуйста алгоритм действий.

Comment: `Google` быстрее ответит на этот вопрос

Answer (score 2):

проще через html,js все сделать в куки то..
с помощью php это может выглядеть следующим образом:
1) в html кнопка "Добавить в корзину" с атрибутом идентификатора товара.
2) при нажатии на кнопку либо 
- отрабатывает js-код, который отправляет ajax-запрос на твой php скрипт 
а-ля
html:

```
<button item-id="item1" onclick="toBasket(this);">Добавить в корзину</button>
```

js:

```
function toBasket(vartt) {
   var item1 = vartt.getAttribute('item1');
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('GET', 'твойскрипт.php?itemId='+item1, false);
   xhr.send();
   if (xhr.status != 200) {
     // обработать ошибку
     alert( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText ); // пример вывода: 404: Not Found
   } else {
     // вывести результат
     alert( xhr.responseText ); // responseText -- текст ответа.
   }   
}
```

php:

```
<?php
$itemId = $_GET['itemId'];
if(isset($_COOKIE['basket']))
   $basket = $_COOKIE['basket'];
else
   $basket = array();
$basket[] = $itemId;
setcookie("basket", $itemId, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
echo 'success!';
```

либо делать через отправку формы, типа
html:

```
<form action="твойскрипт.php" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="идентификатортовара">
<input type="submit" value="отправить" />
</form>
```

php - тот же, что и в примере выше
как-то так.